# Silvester Party in Bratislava

Tags: eastern-europe, nightlife

I am going with some friends to Bratislava for the end of the year.
We are looking for a club. Our requirements are:

- Something that is reachable within 1 hour from the city center, either by public transport or by taxi.
- Entry and drinks should not cost over 500 USD (it's really a max, what I was thinking was about 100/200 USD per person, but if it is really unbelivble cool, well I can think about it).
- Music genre: Techno/House/Electronica.

Comment: 500 dollars per person, or for a group of how many people?

Comment: 500 dollar is really the max, if we can do between 100/200 is better... but I was thinking per person...

Answer (score 2):

For 100-200 USD, you will be a king over here that night, don't worry. :) And about clubs, I don't know events scheduled yet but I'm looking for some big electronic night too...